# Selenium, select value from listbox without using select in Java

Tags: java, selenium

How to select a value from dropdown?

My solution is not working:

```java
Select dropdown_month = new Select(
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]/div[2]"))
);
dropdown_month.selectByVisibleText("July");
```

Comment: Write it as a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to handle `<div>` element while `Select` class should be used only with `<select>` elements.

In your case you might need to use simple `click()` method as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]/div[2]")).click() // To open drop-down
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[.='July']")).click() // To select required option
```